# How to save textarea when updated

Tags: javascript, timer, save, textarea

I have a webpage on my local disk.
i want to save the info in a textarea when ever it is updated.
I want to avoid any third party things like php or any other services.

I want to avoid using a submit button. Only for the information in the text box to stay there  when i relaod the page, close it or even if my pc crashes.

Prefereby to load and save to a local text file.

Im thinking maybe a timer that saves the text value periodically would be good. Like every 10 seconds.

Any ideas would be good. And perhaps a well writyen examplr because i dont habe internet at home or a way to look up things periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with `localStorage`. With the caveat that you’ll lose the data if you clear browser data.

If you want to do the save every 10 sec version then you could do

```
setInterval(function() {
    var value = document.getElementById(“textBox”).value;
    localStorage.setItem(“textValue”, value)
}, 10000)
```

And when the documents load you’ll do the opposite

```
var value = localStorage.getItem(“textValue”)
document.getElementById(“textBox”).value = value
```

Read more on `localStorage` here [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score -1):

you can probably listen to the change event for the text area, and do the work -  if this can happen when the user focus out of the text area.
In case you want to do on every entry then use oninput.

```
<textarea id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()"></textarea>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;  
}
</script>
```